# IPC Communication between Node.js and Java

Tags: java, node.js, ipc, communication

I'm looking to communicate between Node.js and a Java sub-process via IPC. I'm looking for recommendations that **do not** require opening a port.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

// Java App is within args
const args = []

const javaProcess = spawn('java', args, { cwd: __dirname })

javaProcess.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m)
})

// Sends { 'hello': 'world' } to the Java process
javaProcess.send({ hello: 'world' })
```

I understand that the Node layer can send messages to a sub-process, I just don't know how I'd go about listening for messages in the Java layer and sending messages back.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try listening on System.in and responding to System.out

Comment: unix domain socket on *nix or named pipe on windows

Comment: I ended up solving this using named pipes, thanks Hengqi Chen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using named pipes...

On Node I used the Net API
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_ipc_support

On Java I used RandomAccessFile
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with inspiration from [Erwin Bolwidt's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873141/ipc-communication-between-node-js-and-java#comment102171166_57873141).

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

// Java App is within args
const args = []

const javaProcess = spawn('java', args, { cwd: __dirname })

javaProcess.stdout.on('data', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m)
})

// Sends message to the Java process
javaProcess.stdin.write('Hello there java!');
```

The java process can wait for a message with a `Scanner` on `System.in` then print output to `System.out`.

In summary you're just rerouting the process's stdin/stdout. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessstdout